# WHERE LIKE searching in Eloquent with and without spacing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

We've made a search system on our website, with a brands table being made. There are some brands that have spaces in their names and some that don't.

We have for example

> "Turtle Wax"

What I'd like to do, is when a user searches for say **Turtlewax** my search looks for both versions...

- Turtle Wax
- TurtleWax

Is this even possible?

My current code is as follows...

```
$products = Product::select('product.*')
                    ->join('brand', 'product.brand_id', '=', 'brand.id')
                    ->join('child_product', 'product.id', '=', 'child_product.product_id')
                    ->leftJoin('tax_rates', 'tax_rates.id', '=', 'child_product.tax_rate_id')
                    ->with('brand', 'categories', 'childProducts', 'childProducts.attributeValues', 'images')
                    ->where('product.active', true)
                    ->where('brand.active', true)
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($search_term)
                    {
                        $query->whereLike('product.name', $search_term)
                              ->orWhereLike('product.description', $search_term)
                              ->orWhere('brand.slug', str_slug($search_term, ''))
                              ->orWhereLike('brand.slug', str_slug($search_term, '-'))
                              ->orWhereLike('brand.name', str_replace(' ', '', $search_term))
                              ->orWhere('brand.name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search_term);
                    })->get();
```

I have made 2 query scopes for the WhereLike and orWhereLike

```
public function scopeWhereLike($query, $column, $value)
{
    return $query->where($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
}

public function scopeOrWhereLike($query, $column, $value)
{
    return $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
}
```

Comment: If you use PascalCase ("TurtleWax") in the search term, it's splittable. But if you use Titlecase ("Turtlewax"), how should the script know, where to split the word?

Comment: Yeah, this is purely user driven too, so what's to say they're actually going to use Pascal Case. I suppose, I could force it to do that?

Comment: You can't enforce that technically by checking if they're doing that but maybe asking them to do so might suffice, I don't know about your end-users :D

Comment: The MySQL [`soundex`](https://database.guide/mysql-soundex-examples/) function might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Remove spaces from the values (both searching in and searching for) then search. Of course excess matchings are possible, futher manual refine needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're using PascalCase ("TurtleWax"), you can do the following:

```
public function scopeWhereLike($query, $column, $value)
{
    
    return $query
        ->where($column, 'like', '%'.implode(' ', preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $value)).'%') // "word/space case"
        ->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.ucwords(strtolower($value)).'%') // Titlecase
        ->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$value.'%'); // PascalCase
        ->orWhere("REPLACE(".$column.", ' ', '')", 'like', '%'.$value.'%'); // fallback
}
```